# Check the availability of GoogleMaps on Android if not direct to Play store for install

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I implement a drawing route app on GoogleMaps and that is working but first I need  to check for GoogleMaps availablity on Android or not. If the app does not exist, the user should be directed to Google Play Store to install GoogleMaps.

How can I prompt the user to install it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, PackageManager packageManager) {
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packagename, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It attempts to fetch information about the package whose name you passed in. Failing that, if a NameNotFoundException was thrown, it means that no package with that name is installed, so we return false.
in your case

```
     public void someMethod() {
            // ...
        String googleMapsPackageName = "com.google.android.apps.maps"
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        boolean isInstalled = isPackageInstalled(googleMapsPackageName, pm);
        if(isInstalled)
         // go to maps
           else 
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + googleMapsPackageName)));

            // ...
        }
```

Comment: make sure you have added QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission or add the package name you wanna query in manifest using <queries> tag for android >= 11 !  if you use QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES google play asks you to clarify usage of this permission in your app.